# Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Having trouble with XML config files using ElementTree. I want to have an easy way to find the text of an element regardless of where it is in the XML Tree. From what the documentation says, I should be able to do this with findtext(), but no matter what, I get a return of None. Where am I going wrong here? Everyone was telling me XML is so simple to handle in Python, yet I have had nothing but troubles.

```
configFileName = 'file.xml'

def configSet (x):
if os.path.exists(configFileName):
    tree = ET.parse(configFileName)
    root = tree.getroot()
    return root.findtext(x)

hiTemp = configSet('hiTemp')
print hiTemp
```

and the XML

```
<configData>
<units>
    <temp>F</temp>
</units>
<pins>
    <lights>1</lights>
    <fan>2</fan>
    <co2>3</co2>
</pins>
<events>
    <airTemps>
        <hiTemp>80</hiTemp>
        <lowTemp>72</lowTemp>
        <hiTempAlarm>84</hiTempAlarm>
    </airTemps>
    <CO2>
        <co2Hi>1500</co2Hi>
        <co2Low>1400</co2Low>
        <co2Alarm>600</co2Alarm>
    </CO2>
</events>
<settings>
    <apikeys>
        <prowl>
            <apikey>None</apikey>
        </prowl>
    </apikeys>
</settings>
```

expected result

```
80
```

actual result

```
None
```

Comment: It could be that `os.path.exists(configFileName)` returned `False`. Add `else: raise IOError("File not found.")` to see if that's the case.

Comment: It is finding the file, because I can do return root and it gives me the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findtext` requires a full path, but you have given a relative path, so you cannot find the element you are looking for.

You can either provide a good xpath or modify your code

```
def configSet(x):
    if os.path.exists(configFileName):
        tree = ET.parse(configFileName)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for e in root.getiterator():
           t = e.findtext(x)
           if t is not None:
               return t
```

**Update 1:**

If you want to have all matched text as a list, the code is a bit different.

```
def configSet(x):
    matches = []
    if os.path.exists(configFileName):
        tree = ET.parse(configFileName)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for e in root.getiterator():
           t = e.findtext(x)
           if t is not None:
               matches.append(t)
    return matches
```

Comment: This is it! Awesome, but can you explain what for e in root.getiterator is actually doing? What does the getiterator function call do to allow this recurrsive type search?

Comment: @user3724263 The function `getiterator` creates a tree iterator with the current element as the root. The iterator iterates over this element and all elements below it, in document (depth first) order. `e` stands for current element of the iteration trip.

Comment: So it basically loops through the entire XML until e.findtext is found? Or it goes through the entire XML only returning things that are not None?

Comment: @user3724263 Loops through the entire XML, until the first match of `e.findtext` is found. If nothing is found, then return `None` instead. I've added a secondary code to return all matches as a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xpath to get to your desired element.

`return root.find('./events/airTemps/hiTemp').text`

There's easy to follow [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example).

Comment: Is there anyway to find it without knowing the path? I highly doubt there would ever be a reason why the path would change, but I am curious I guess you could say. For instance, how would it work for a setting outside of events airtemps and find the value for lights under pins using the same function?

Comment: @rinti I've tried `.//*hiTemp`. If xml contains a `ahiTemp` before `hiTemp`, etree reports an error. `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: ahiTemp line 12 and hiTemp, line 12, column 29`